# Declare a cv::Mat of NaN

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, nan, mat

In OpenCV I'm trying to declare a `cv::Mat` and initializing it with NaN values. Kinda similar to:

```
myMat = Mat(nrows, ncols, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
```

But instead of 0, I'd like NaN's. How can I do this? And what type should I set for NaN values?

Comment: apart from the problem, that there's no portable way to express NaN (it's compiler dependant), a uchar can only hold values in the [0..255] range, and they're all valid.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do such thing?

Answer (score 6):

There is no NaN for integer types, but depending on your C++ compiler you may have NaN with `float` and `double` data (`CV_32F` and `CV_64F`).  Use `std::numeric_limits<T>::has_quiet_NaN()` to check if a type `T` has a NaN value, and then `std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN()` to get the value.

```
double dNaN = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
cv::Mat myMat = Mat(nrows, ncols, CV_64F, cv::Scalar(dNaN));
```

Comment: @user2121792 If this worked out or was correct in your case, could you accept the answer?  Feel free to add details if you were after something different.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: cool, but only for float types, not for the uchar version, the original question was about

Comment: @berak Yeah, that's why i edited my answer.  I realized I didn't make that point (there is no special value for integer types as you commented originally) explicit.  Sometimes the answer is "you can't", I think.